# MySQL Server stops on Ubuntu 14.04 Server after sometime

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04

I am running a VPS and everything works but after 20-30 hours MySQL process stops running. The PHP error I see is **`[2002] SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory`** and the solution is to start it using the command:

```
sudo service mysql start
```

I have created a CRONJOB with this command to overcome the issue but definitely this is not the solution. How to know and fix the real problem?

Comment: this belongs on dba.

Comment: it is common problem on MySQL, It related to socket. see http://prattski.com/2010/08/05/magento-install-mysql-error-sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory/

Comment: @houssam its surprising that after so many years, MySQL hasn't solved this problem

Comment: @MuhammadAhmadZafar : do you mean that the number 2002 is related to the year? I don't think that.